# google cloud , directadmin - how to set up custom nameservers for domain?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, nameservers, directadmin, google-cloud-dns

I have installed directadmin in a google virtual machine. I can access directadmin from an external IP and it works fine, but I can't access directadmin from a domain name.

I want to change the default nameservers, for example "ns1.example.com" and "ns2.example.com". I want to use Google Cloud for shared hosting.

I changed the default name server records to ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com 
then added A records for these name servers, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart) is what you're looking for, as it will allow you to use your own domain for your DirectAdmin installation (and anything else you'd like).